# Convert bash array to a single stringified shell argument list, handable by "sh -c"

Tags: bash, escaping

This question looks similar to many questions on SO, but I didn't find a real answer.

Sometimes I need to run `sh -c "$my_command"`, where `$my_command` has to be created from a bash array of arguments (whatever the arguments look like).

Here is my solution, but I wonder if there is a better, (maybe native) bash solution for this?

```
#!/bin/bash

# My solution:
args_to_shell_escaped_string() {
    local arg
    for arg in "$@"; do
        printf '%q ' "$arg"
    done
}

# Testing it:
args=(
    'arg with spaces'
    'arg with; !! any { special $char'
)

escaped_args=$(args_to_shell_escaped_string "${args[@]}")

sh -c "
for a in $escaped_args; do
    echo \">> \$a\"
done
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the `Q` parameter transformation.

```
sh -c "
for a in ${args[*]@Q}; do
    echo \">> \$a\"
done
"
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is to just pass your arguments as positional arguments to the program.

```
sh -c 'for a ; do echo ">> $a" ; done' _ "${args[@]}"
```

I'd personally argue that it's bad practice to embed variables directly into a `sh -c` command even if you're trying to take special care to escape them. One missed escape is all it takes to introduce bugs or security flaws.